# Array subtraction in a loop

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, operation

I created an array of 222 rows and 3 columns. After that I put some values (x,y,z) in row 222. Now I would like do the following:

```
// create an array of 222 rows and 3 columns filled with zeros 
public float[,] arrayPosSpheres = new float[222, 3];


enter code here//loop change of x value for each of the spheres 

    for (int k = 220; k = 0; k--) {

        arrayPosSpheres [k, 0] =  arrayPosSpheres [k + 1, 0] - sizeSphere * overlay;


    }
```

So I would like to have a value row 220, column 0 which would be the value of row 221 and column 0 minus something. However, I got an error.

Assets/Scripts/SineWaveSpheres.cs(138,51): error CS0019: Operator `-' cannot be applied to operands of type`float' and `UnityEngine.Vector3'

Assets/Scripts/SineWaveSpheres.cs(136,17): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `int' to`bool'

How can I do this?

Comment: The error message is quite self-explanatory. You probably want to use `UnityEngine.Vector3`'s [length](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-magnitude.html) while making the calculations. Also, recommended reading - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, the second error is probably related to the `k = 0` in the for-loop. This must be a bool expression, so something like `k >= 0` or `k == 0`. The other error occurs somewhere else according to the error code (line 51) and means that you try to do a subtraction with a `float` and a `Vector3` which you can't do directly. I'd need to see more of the code to say further.

Comment: Using a List<> object instead of an array will make it much easier to add items to an existing array/list object.

Comment: The * operand has presidents over the - operand.  So sizeShere is being multilpied by overlay and getting a vector.  Then the vector cannot be subtracted from you array of [222,3].

Answer (score 1):

In the `for` loop you assign 0 to `k` instead of checking if k is equals or bigger than `k`

```
for (int k = 220; k >= 0; k--)
```

As a side note, try to avoid fixed numbers. `arrayPosSpheres.GetLength(0);` will return the length of the rows, i.e. 222. Initalize `k` with it and subtract from it 2 for the indexes and fixed value at the end

```
for (int k = arrayPosSpheres.GetLength(0) - 2; k >= 0; k--)
```